# CRUD with web api in ember.js, $.ajax or restAdapter?

Tags: ajax, rest, ember.js, asp.net-web-api

I want to create crud component in ember , I dont know What is the difference between using $.ajax jquery and restAdapter in ember.js ? Which one is better for communication with Web api?

Comment: Can you give more explanations, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. The path of least resistance would be to use ember data, but that assumes some degree of consistency in how the API is structured.